# I cant convert from string to int

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

Im using regex to scrape the number from website and then i want to mypltiply that by 4.

```
Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Views"">\(....)")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(thepage)

Dim kwota As String

For Each itemcode As Match In matches
    kwota = itemcode.Groups(1).Value
Next

Dim stringToInteger As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(kwota)
```

After that I've got an error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`. I dont know how to make it. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio, VB .net. The `kwota` variable contains `15.2` as a string.

Comment: you are creating an int (stringToInteger) and assigning it to textbox1.text (which is a string).

Comment: The thing is, that the error shows even if i delete assign to textbox

Comment: Well, `15.2` is definitely not `int`, it is `double`, `float` or `decimal`.

Comment: I changed to `Dim tehe As Double = Convert.ToDouble(text)` and it's doesnt change anything :/

Comment: can you post all of your code please including the website you are attempting to scrape and ill go over the code for you.

Comment: Someone else posted that `Val` is good, and i used `Dim stringToDouble As Double = (CDbl(Val(kwota))) * 4`. Its working properly. But what is the reason that `Convert.ToDouble(text)` or `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(kwota))` doesnt worked properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Val function is fairly robust. Try:

```
Dim stringToInteger As Integer = CInt(Val(kwota))
```

Comment: Wow! Its working. But why `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(kwota))` or `Convert.ToDouble(text)` doesnt worked?

Comment: @audiophonic If this is the solution you should give it the check

Comment: @audiophonic The FormatException is being raised by the Convert.ToDouble method. (The Convert.ToInt32 only raises an overflow exception.) I suspect that the string has an extra character, perhaps a space or tab, that Convert.ToDouble can't handle. The Val function can deal with extra characters beyond the number. And yes, a check would be nice.

Comment: Val should only EVER be used as a last resort. It's an old VB6 method that has gone way past its "use by" date. It has some wonky side effects that can be really hard to troubleshoot once they creep into your code. The reason why your attempts fail is that you were trying to explicitly convert `15.2` to an integer. That value is not an integer so it fails. `Val` on the other hand, converts to the closest possible data type (in your case probably a single) but you have NO control what it's being converted to.

Comment: @Jeroen Not quite true. Convert.Int32 can accept a double without an issue. The OP reported that the exception was a FormatException, which is raised by Covert.ToDouble. The developer should inspect the string (he didn't provide it) to determine what is being passed in kwota. Perhaps the RegEx can be improved, or a simple fix like trimming it first, can avoid the FormatException.

Comment: @JerryM also not entirely true :-) `Convert.ToInt32` will happily chop the decimals off a double, but ONLY if it is passed as a double, `MsgBox(Convert.ToInt32(15.2))` works, `MsgBox(Convert.ToInt32("15.2"))` doesn't. My issue was with the use of Val. Agreed, OP should change the regex.

Comment: Like I said before, the use of Val should be discouraged, not promoted. http://www.owenpellegrin.com/articles/vb-net/converting-strings-to-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to integer, convert the string to a float, then to integer.

```
Dim stringToInteger As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(kwota))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex. Where you simply have 5 dots could be written as: `\d+\.\d+` which means, match one or more numerics followed by a literal period followed by one or more numerics. That way you know you are grabbing a number and not whatever other crap may be on that web page.

Disclaimer: I would have to see the HTML to see if the regex is "fit for purpose" the way it is written.